# Azure Data Factory automatically adding Date to a Time column while importing an Excel file

Tags: azure-data-factory, import-from-excel

I have a time column in Excel that contains values of Time Type in the following format:

```
03:11:00
```

When I add the Excel File as a Source in ADF, it automatically converts it to DateTime and when I preview the data I see this:

```
1899-12-31 03:11:00.0000000
```

What can I do to prevent this conversion from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add an Excel file as a source in ADF, it automatically converts the time column to DateTime in data preview. To convert, you can use the `Data Flow` activity in ADF and use the `Derived Column` transformation to convert the DateTime column back to the original time format. You can use the `substring` function to extract the time part of the timestamp. Here is an example expression that you can use in the `Derived Column` transformation:

```
substring(<DateTimeColumn>, 12, 8)
```

Replace `<DateTimeColumn>` with the name of your DateTime column. This expression will extract the time part of the DateTime column in the format `hh:mm:ss`.

[image]